# How can I make a python program executable from the command line universally?

Tags: python, macos, command-line

I'm writing a Python CLI program, and I want to be able to execute it from any location, a la VIM simply by typing "atsushi" and not having the user CD to the program directory.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: put script in folder which is in system's variable `PATH` Or add folder with script to this variable.

Comment: @furas This is not specific.

Comment: it is method used in Windows and Linux but on MacOS it may also work. You should check in command line `echo $PATH`

Comment: On Linux you have also set attribut "executable" - `chmod +x script.py` and add `shebang` (`#!`) in first line of code ie. `#!/usr/bin/env python`. And then it runs it using `script.py` instead of `python `script.py`. Because MacOS is based on Unix so it may use the same method.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you're already able to run it with `./atsushi` in its directory)

Put it in a directory in the `PATH` environment variable:

- **System** - any user can run it

  Put it in `/usr/local/bin`, which is already in the system `PATH`,
  as defined in `/etc/paths`. You'll need admin privileges for this.
- **User** - only you can run it

  Put it in a subdirectory of your home directory (e.g. `~/bin`) and add
  that to your user's PATH by adding a line like this to `~/.bash_profile`:

  ```
  PATH=$PATH:~/bin
  ```

  Restart your shell to have the new `PATH` take effect.

You might want to symlink it into the directory instead of copying it. This has various pros and cons.